# How to copy a hyperlink to a cell with only the path?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a code that uses a `for` loop to open a list of workbooks and copy the data from the opened workbook to the active workbook.

I have figured out how to copy the data however I want to add a hyperlink for each workbook. The path to each file is found in the `strPath` string.

I want to assign the hyperlink to the cell :

`sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn)` 
(note that date column is just the column number I find thanks to the `FindDate` function.)

Here is what I have so far:

```
For index = 3 To 37 
    dateColumn = FindDate(portfolioDate)
    portfolioName = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & index & "").Value & ".xls"
    strPath = "G:\Risk\Risk Reports\VaR-Stress test\" & portfolioDate & "\" & portfolioName & ""

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath)     
    sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn).Value = wb.Close Savechanges:=False
Next index
```

Comment: What does the `sheet` variable refer to in `sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your syntax is wrong.

Please try the following at the Set:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath)     
    sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn).Value = strPath
With sheet 
   .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(index, dateColumn), _ 
   Address:=strPath, _ 
   ScreenTip:="Path to the file", _ 
   TextToDisplay:="File Path to " & "\" & portfolioName & portfolioDate ' Change strPath as per your Requirement to display a different text
End With
wb.Close Savechanges:=False
```

But i'm not sure if the `sheet` in your code is a variable.

Comment: it is ! It's just that I only included what is relevant to my question

Comment: Okay, in that case the above code should probably work. I've just made a change to include hyperlink.

Comment: it worked ! thanks a lot! is there a way to leave this hyperlink but name it differently?

Comment: Yes, you can change the `TextToDisplay` part of the `Hyperlink` function. Replace `strPath` with whatever you like

Comment: I have edited the code to display the Portfolio Name & Date